# Delete HTTP request in Ruby produces 401 unauthorized

Tags: ruby, filepicker.io

The code snippet below gives me a `401 unauthorized` response. This code works if I change the HTTP method from Delete to Get or Post:

```
url = 'https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/LYsl3wunQBW0to2JD4D4'
polysig_str = "?policy=#{policy}&signature=#{signature}"

uri = URI.parse(url)
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host)
req = Net::HTTP::Delete.new(uri.path + polysig_str)
response = http.request(req)
```

My policy and signature are set prior to this code snippet and, like I said, work fine if I just do the Get request, I can see the file data in the response. I've also tried posting to this url:

```
url = 'https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/LYsl3wunQBW0to2JD4D4/remove'
```

Same result: 401 unauthorized.

I've tried including the `call: 'remove'` in the policy and `handle: 'LYsl3wunQBW0to2JD4D4'`.

The signature and policy seem to be correct because if I create an expired policy or only include `call: 'read'`, I get a `403 Forbidden` response instead of the 401.

I just can't figure out how to delete the record from an HTTP request. The interesting thing is I can Post to that URL and overwrite the contents of the file but I can't Delete it completely (Everything in Ruby).

Maybe it's only possible to remove files using the proprietary JS library provided by Filepicker?

Comment: doesn't seems to be anything wrong. Remove rest api: https://www.filepicker.com/documentation/file_ingestion/rest_api/remove You may want to check if you policy allows you to remove files (it may not allow you to do that and the 401 is normal in this case)

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to add my Filepicker app key to the parameters as well:

```
polysig_str = "?key=#{key}&policy=#{policy}&signature=#{signature}"
```

Make sure you create the key variable before that line and set it equal to your Filepicker app key (same goes for policy and signature).

Now I can send HTTP Delete requests in Ruby.